# How to create alternating rows in a table?

Tags: tables, color, backgrounds

Sometimes you can see in books tables, that have alternating background color for rows in a table to support readability. How I can achieve this with LaTeX?

And yes, I could put macros `\odd` and `\even` into each row, but in that case I would have to change all following rows, if I input later another row into the table. I want TeX to decide itself, which row is odd or even and put the appropiate style into it.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use the features of the [colortbl](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) package with additions of [xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). See code below for a small example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    Table head & Table head\\
    Some values & Some values\\
    Some values & Some values\\
    Some values & Some values\\
    Some values & Some values\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The particular package manuals have the details.

Comment: If there are some other languages text in the table, please do not use the the order "\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}"

Comment: Actually, the `\rowcolors` command is not referenced anywhere in the manual. Only the `\rowcolor` without the `s`. Any idea on how to make color alternate every n row ?

Comment: Be careful with this approach: in my setup it colored the part of equations typeset with `\begin{cases}\end{cases}`

Comment: Can the gray color start from the second row instead of first one ?

Comment: @alper change the order of colors: ```\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}```

Comment: I noticed that in TeXstudio, applying the rowcolors caused some table lines to disappear. They are actually not gone, but just not rendered. This is weird because I didn't change the pdf view at all. The lines appear by increasing the zoom level in the pdf viewer or using another pdf viewer.

Answer (score 35):

This can easily be achieved using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). It is explained at [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Alternate_row_colors_in_tables), you just add the `table` option to `\usepackage{xcolor}` and in the table itself you put

```
\rowcolors{1}{color-1}{color-2}
```

Answer (score 32):

One thing that might be worth pointing out, is that apparently, many packages call on `xcolor`, and I had endless clashes first time I tried it, and it took me such a long time to figure this one out, so I felt it might help someone as slow as me to mention this: The xcolor package should be loaded last (or at least after the clashing packages).

Comment: Thanks, I could reproduce the clash, but had it not in first place, because I added it at the end anyways. But that was pure chance, so others might run into this problem.

Comment: I had that clash using beamer. Since beamer loads xcolor internally, you cannot add `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` just to specify the table option.
Therefore you have to put the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` before the `\documentclass{..}`. Hope somebody else can use this :-)

Comment: Thank you Bertram, this was exactly the solution I was looking for. I was using the tufte-book class. Now it works flawlessly ;) \PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor} \documentclass{..}

Comment: Another approach which might be worth trying in this case (xcolor already loaded by another package): just load colortbl instead of xcolor.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen this does not work because the command `\rowcolors` is not defined by `colortbl` but by `xcolor` if the `table` option is used. Therefore your solution doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @BertramNudelbach An alternative to the solution using `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` is to load the `beamer` package with the option `xcolor=table` as specified in the [Beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on p. 19.

Answer (score 5):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has tools in order to color cells, rows and columns in a convenient way.

Morevorer, with `nicematrix` you won't have the thin white lines you see in some PDF viewers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\Body
Table head & Table head\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Some values\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the firstcode]

You can also color the rows with any cycle of colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}
\CodeBefore
  \rowlistcolors{1}{red!15,blue!15,green!15}
\Body
  Mathilde \\
  Pierre \\
  Paul \\
  Juliette \\
  Jacques \\
  Antoine \\
  Emmanuelle \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: You could elaborate on *why* you won't see the "thin white lines" (because the row colours are drawn across the entire row rather than on a cell-by-cell basis), but then also mention that at the first go-around, you need to compile *three* times. Subsequent compilations may require fewer runs if nothing changes in terms of the tabular position. However, just mentioning `{NiceTabular}` and boasting about the positive things only is being biased...

Comment: @Werner: In fact, with `nicematrix`, if you use `\cellcolor{...}` in two adjacent cells (with the same color), you won't see thin white lines. The package has been designed to avoid those thin lines even if it is on a cell-by-cell basis. For the compilations, I have said that several (several) compilations may be needed.

Comment: Ahhh, I see that now.

Comment: For the long lines can it add auto newline at the end of each line instead of continue

Comment: @alper: In `{NiceTabular}`, you can use columns of type `p`, `b` and `m` as in standard `{tabular}` (of the  package `array`).

Comment: I was able to make it work with following paramteres: `\begin{NiceTabular}{|Y{0.125}|P{0.8}|}`

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://texblog.org/2011/09/02/coloring-every-alternate-table-row/) says if you want to apply alternating colors (white, then lightgray) to all your tables, you can use pure TeX to "redefine the tabular environment":

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.94}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{2}{lightgray}{white}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}
```

I edited the example slightly to make white first, and the lightgray lighter.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with `tblr` and `booktabs` environments of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: alternating rows work well even if you have changed the vertical space between them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {rccc},
  row{odd} = {blue8},
  row{even} = {azure8},
  row{1} = {purple8},
}  
\hline[2pt]
  Thing & Value & Value & Value \\
\hline[1pt]
      A & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
      B & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
      C & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
      D & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
      E & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\hline[2pt]
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec = {rccc},
  row{odd} = {blue8},
  row{even} = {azure8},
  row{1} = {purple8},
}
\toprule
  Thing & Value & Value & Value \\
\midrule
      A & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
      B & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
      C & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\specialrule{2pt,teal5}{0pt}{2pt}
      D & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\addlinespace[3pt]
      E & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{multirow} 

\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{graphicx} %rotate text
 \usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}







\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\centering
\caption{Multirow table with continuous coloring.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
-&-\\
-&-\\
\cellcolor{green}&Single-row\\
\cellcolor{green}&Single-row\\
%\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{-3}{*}{Rotating}} & working row \\
\cellcolor{green}\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$job\_id$}}} & working row \\
-&-\\
-&-\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%



\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}\hline
~ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & {\hfill Text\hfill} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\centering rotato-ata}}} & text &&&&\\
& text &testing A& testing B&&\\
& text &right aligned&&&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\centering
\caption{Multirow table with all cells in the same color.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
-                       &       -       \\
-                       &       -       \\
\cellcolor{green} Text Green   &   Single-row  \\
\cellcolor{yellow} &   Single-row  \\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor{red}Text of -3, Misplaced}&Single-row\\
-                       &       -       \\
-                       &       -       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%


\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\centering
\caption{Multirow table with all rows in the same color.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
-                       &       -       \\
-                       &       -       \\
\rowcolor{green}        &   Single-row  \\
\rowcolor{yellow}       &   Single-row  \\
\rowcolor{red}\multirow{-3}{*}{Text}&Single-row\\
-                       &       -       \\
-                       &       -       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%



\end{document}
```