# How to color alternate rows in latex?

Tags: tables, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create alternating rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-to-create-alternating-rows-in-a-table)

I am working on colored table but i need make alternate table colorful.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% new colours
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15] 
\textbf{Detailed Test Table} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}c >{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{6cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{orange}   \textbf{data} &\textbf{dummy} &\textbf{value} &\textbf{rough} &\textbf{text}\\ 
\hline 
\rowcolor{lightgray}        rsxx  & CreT  & 17603472, 19141561  & twet  & 17603472, 19141561\\ 
                     rs7193xx343  & TrT  & 19597491, 21760908  & twer  & 19597491, 21760908\\ 
                       rxx376333  & CCe  & 2017r3747  & twertw  & 20173747\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 

\end{document}
```

How can i implement it?

Comment: Follow the instructions given in the link provided by **Jake** in his comment, but load `xcolor` *before* `mdframed`.

Comment: I used xcolor but it is not working. I have already closed my previous thread. Pls reply for this.

Comment: I am using following package. \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}                                      I think there is clash among packages. How can i avoid such clashes.

Comment: You can open a new question with a full (non)working MWE for the `clash` issue.

Comment: @manish: That's why Gonzalo told you to load `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` *before* `mdframed`. You're loading it afterwards, which causes the clash.