# How to change row height within xtable environment?

Tags: formatting, knitr, height, xtable

I would like to change row height such that all rows except the header row will have fix height x and the header row will have eight y. I would like to do this  within `xtable` environment because I need to generate this table inside a knitr code chunk. I want to retain all other formating used in the code example (each second row gray and the last column in italics).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
 <<do_table2, results = "asis">>=
    library(xtable)
    mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
    rws <- seq(1, (nrow(head(iris))-1), by = 2)
    col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws))

    iris$Species <- paste0("\\textit{", iris$Species, "}")
    rep("\\[5pt]", nrow(head(iris)))

    print(xtable(head(iris)),
       add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col),
       sanitize.text.function = identity)

    @
\end{document}
```

Note: Firstly I tried to change row height at least somehow. I wanted to use `add.to.row` with `command` argument  `rep("\\[20pt]", length(rws))`, but this placed the command in front of the line and therefore did not work.

```
\[20pt]6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & \textit{\textit{\textit{\textit{setosa}}
```

So I tried to put it in the end like this: `iris$Species <- paste0("\\textit{", iris$Species, "}\\[20pt]")` or `iris$Species <- paste0("\\textit{", iris$Species, "}\\[20pt]\\")`, but I also did not succeed.

Edit:
From the latex point of view I need to change line height inside a line such that the command will be in the very beginning of the line like this, but this does not worked me:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
  \hline
 & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
  \hline
1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
   \\[20pt]2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
  3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
   \\[20pt]4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
  5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa \\ 
   \\[20pt]6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The LaTeX command should have two backslashes. `\\[20pt]` --- could just be a problem of escaping? I do not know which languages is that, but in python I need `"\\\\[20pt]"` (notice the *four* backslash). Anyway, if you post a MWE **in LaTeX** we could help better.

Comment: OK, here is the knitr MWE.
The content of the code chunk is R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LaTeX, the fact that the `\\` is at the start or at the end of the (text) line means nothing. Your problem is that you have blank lines (repeated `\\` and then `\\[20pt]`  following...

Try to generate something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
    \hline
    & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
    \hline
    \\[20pt]1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa  
    \\[20pt]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

(BTW: this is a correct MWE. Copy, paste and compile).

[image: ugly table here]

Although to maintain constant height, I would rather use a `\strut` or an invisible rule at the start of the line. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\newcommand{\splat}{\vrule width 0 pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
    \hline
    \splat & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
    \hline
    \splat 1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \splat 2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \splat 3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \splat 4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \splat 5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \splat 6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

And you can control the *minimum* size of a row by playing with the `depth` and `height` parameters in the definition of `\splat`.

[image: Better looking table]

And, if you really do not want to access the preamble of your LaTeX (but this is really limiting, so try to learn how to) and your `xtable` thing loads the appropriate packages (as it seems, otherwise `\rowcolor` would not be available) you can simply expand your macros manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrl}
    \hline
    \vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax & Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species \\ 
    \hline
    \vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 1 & 5.10 & 3.50 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \rowcolor{gray}{0.8}\vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 2 & 4.90 & 3.00 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 3 & 4.70 & 3.20 & 1.30 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \rowcolor{gray}{0.8}\vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 4 & 4.60 & 3.10 & 1.50 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 5 & 5.00 & 3.60 & 1.40 & 0.20 & setosa  \\
    \rowcolor{gray}{0.8}\vrule width 0pt height 15pt depth 5pt\relax 6 & 5.40 & 3.90 & 1.70 & 0.40 & setosa  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

to obtain:

[image: zebra table]

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to generate your code in knitr and it worked.
I do not how to use \strut inside knitr/xtable. With a table generated manually inside LaTeX this would be better.
Would you know how to combine your code with this one \\rowcolor[gray]{0.8} for some (each second) of my rows?
BTW. My code in the question is a  MWE but for knitr no pure LaTeX

Comment: A `\strut` is similar to the invisible rule I defined in `\splat`, but with the font height and depth. To color every other row, you can let LaTeX do it:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-to-create-alternating-rows-in-a-table

Comment: Thanks, but would it be possible to do this inside lines? I do not know how to put a command to an extra line into xtable... I do not want to modify the LaTeX code...