# LaTeX Table matching solutions to problems

Tags: tables

I would like to create a table like this, but I have no idea of how to do it. Could you please help me with it? Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which are the features of the table you want to copy ? vertical labels on the top ? grey rows ? Crossed upper-left cell ?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Also make sure to check for existing questions with similar topics, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-to-create-alternating-rows-in-a-table, https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btables%5D+diagonal

Comment: @Julie: PS: as is, my previous comments might appear a bit rude for your first question, but please do not take it personally. We're actually kind inside `(-:` What makes this site usefull and efficient are its -sometimes implicit for a new user- rules that I tried to explain, that's all. We all aked such a question (so don't worry about it), but this is not the best way to get a quick answer... and to learn by yourself!