# Problem in creating a tcolorbox table

Tags: tcolorbox

does any body know how to this kind of coloured boxes in latex? I have tried, but i failed dramatically

[image]

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! please, show to us, what you tray so far and where you stack. otherwise this is "do-it-for-me" question ... which have low probabilities to be answered.

Comment: Relevant http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/124842

Comment: As a minimum, please provide code that replicates a standard table we can use as foundation...

Comment: sorry well, before this replay i had try this sequence that i  had search in the internet                                                                       
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4,raster equal height,
colframe=red!75!black,colback=red!5!white,fonttitle=\bfseries]
\tcbitem[squeezed title={Eventos}]
\end{tcbitemize} And work is not bad, the ting is wit this i got 4 separate colored boxes as you can see but i was unable to replicate this one that i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v224a]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularx}    
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
{   \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}\arrayrulecolor{white}
    \sffamily
    \rowcolors{2}{cyan!20}{cyan!10!gray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|C|C|C}
\rowcolor{cyan!50!gray}
\color{white}   Event           &   \color{white}  Number of Years Ago
                                    &   \color{white}   Number of Days Ago on Calendar
                                        &   \color{white}   Date/Time on calendar   \\
    \hline
xxx                             & y & y & Jan. 1, 12 am     \\
    \hline
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx & y yy yyy yyyy yyyyy
                                    & y & Jan. 1, 12 am     \\
    \hline
xxx xxx xxx                     &   &   &                   \\
    \hline
xx xxx xxxx xxxxx           &   &   &                   \\
  \end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Real content of table and selection desired row colors I left to you :).

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for not posting what i ad done.  I had other way, but they didn't like what i did. I had four separate coloured boxes one next to the other, that i knew how to do it but i could,'t do what you just did thanks.