# Coloring Rows in a Spaced Table

Tags: tables, spacing, color, rowcolor

I am trying to create a table with fractions in it and every other row being coloured. Because of the fractions, I am having to space out the rows in the table, but this seems to be conflicting with the colouring of the rows and now the colouring isn't working.

Here is where my code is at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{c | cc | cc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Parameters} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\ \midrule
\rowcolor{Gray} $(2, n, 3)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{2}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{2}$ \\

$(2, n, 4)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{3}$ \\

\rowcolor{Gray} $(4, n, 8)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{4}$ & $\displaystyle 4$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{5}{8}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{8}{5}$ \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Comparison of A and B}
  \label{tab:results}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

which produces the following table:

[image: Picture of table produced]

which I am happy with, but I would like the second and fourth rows shaded.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/124842

Comment: Thank you, but I have done multiple examples with coloured rows, I just can't get it working in this one particular example. I have just tried to combine my spaced table with the example in the link you just gave, and it compiles fine with no errors, yet the rows are still not shaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's indeed  a problem with (part of) `makecell` and colours in tables. There's also a problem with `booktabs`: rules have some vertical padding and this produces white strips at top and bottom of coloured rows. The simplest solution consists in suppressing this padding in coloured tables, and replacing it with a customised padding obtained with `cellspace`.

In the following code I replaced the old `color` package with `xcolor` and option `[table]`, which makes loading `colortbl` needless, and adds new functionalities with the `\rowcolors`command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\rowcolors{1}{}{Gray}
  \begin{tabular}{Sc | ScSc | cc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Parameters} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\ \midrule
  $(2, n, 3)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{2}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{2}$ \\

    $(2, n, 4)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{3}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{3}$ \\

     $(4, n, 8)$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{4}$ & $\displaystyle 4$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{5}{8}$ & $\displaystyle \dfrac{8}{5}$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{Comparison of A and B}
  \label{tab:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Congrats to 100k!!!!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Thanks! Do I deserve a glass of champagne?

Comment: @Bernard: Well, ... uhmm.... ask the other 100k users in chat please ;-)

Comment: @Bernard Please, if you can, make a visit to the chat! We should have a party for you! Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks @egreg! How can I visit the chat? I can see no access point on the site. Note I was just joking for champagne (albeit I love it…)

Comment: @Bernard http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Answer (score 1):

You can do that table very easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. With that environment you can draw vertical rules comptaible with the rules of `booktabs` (even if it's not at all in the spirit of `booktabs` to draw vertical rules). You have tools to color rows in a way compatible with `booktabs` and you have an built-in key `cell-space-limits` (no need of `cellspace`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|cc|cc}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors[gray]{1}{}{0.9}
\Body
  \toprule
  \textbf{Parameters} & \Block{1-2}{A} && \Block{1-2}{B} \\ \midrule
   $(2, n, 3)$ & $\dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\dfrac{3}{2}$ & $\dfrac{2}{3}$ & $\dfrac{3}{2}$ \\
   $(2, n, 4)$ & $\dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\dfrac{4}{3}$ & $\dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\dfrac{4}{3}$ \\
   $(4, n, 8)$ & $\dfrac{1}{4}$ & $4$ & $\dfrac{5}{8}$ & $\dfrac{8}{5}$ \\ \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Comparison of A and B}
\label{tab:results}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]