# Improve table formatting

Tags: tables, formatting

How can I add banded colored rows to this table format ?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | *{5}{p{1.8cm}|}  \hline
\ & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title}  \\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{subhead} \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/121944

Comment: Also your `tabular` line should read `\begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | *{5}{p{1.8cm}}|}  \hline`. I.e., you're missing a `}` after `1.8cm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are banded rows, thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5365/121944) and use of `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3.40cm} | *{5}{p{1.8cm}}|}  \hline
\rowcolor{gray!50} % comment out if you don't want top row colored
\ & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title} & \b{Title}  \\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{subhead} \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text} & {text}  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]